# Cocos2D: Create sprite from a file in documents directory

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

What is the best way to create instance of CCSprite from downloaded image file?

I would like to implement downloadable additional contents in my Cocos2D game.

The way I used is

1. Create UImage from a downloaded image.
2. Create CCTexture2D from UIImage.
3. Create CCSprite from CCTexture2D.

If you know more smart way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my tutorial [How to Download (only) Modified Files from a Webserver](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/01/download-modified-files-web-server-cocos2d-webcam-viewer/). I used this to build a Cocos2D Webcam Viewer and contains example code for downloading files via NSData, saving it to the documents directory and creating a texture/sprite from the downloaded image file.

Comment: Could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098574/add-spriteframe-from-documents-folder-in-cocos2d-v2 ? I need to load downloaded spriteframes using Cocos2D-v2

Answer (score 2):

If you have a UIImage named img;

sprite can be created by

```
CCSprite *s = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:img.CGImage key:@"image"];
```